# AR(2) Characteristic Equation Equivalence

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

In a recent question I was given the AR(2) process
$$
Y_t = \phi_1Y_{t-1} + \phi_2Y_{t-2} + \epsilon_t
$$

And I determined that the characteristic equation should be
$$
\phi(z)=1-\phi_1z-\phi_2z^2
$$

However, when finding the roots of the equations, I have been told that
$$
\phi(z)=1-\phi_1z-\phi_2z^2 = 0
$$
Is equivalent to
$$
C(z) =z^2 -\phi_1z-\phi_2=0
$$
Does this make sense? How do you come about this conclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The roots of $\phi(z)$ and $C(z)$ are reciprocals of each other. To see it, just substitute $z^{-1}$ instead of $z$ in $\phi(z)$ and multiply each side of the equation with $z^2$. Thus, you'll obtain $C(z)$. Here, *equivalence* does not mean that $C(z)$ and $\phi(z)$ have the same $z$ roots; but they're closely related.